# PHP проверка на наличие в конце строки точки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, строки

Есть код

```
 $preg = '|^[A-Z\s]+$|i';
    $check = preg_match($preg, $_POST['string']);
    if ($check == true) {do smth}
      else {do smth}
```

проверят строку на наличие символов англ. алфавита и пробельных символов.
Стоит задача проверять есть ли точка в конце строки (не больше 1).

Comment: ну так добавьте эту самую точку перед концом строки т.е. перед `$` не забыв ее заэкранировать обратной косой

Comment: а зачем вы привели этот кусочек кода, который не имеет отношения к вашей проблеме?

Comment: Проблема была в том, что нужно было учитывать чтобы в строке между словами были пробельные символы и точку в конце именно самой строки, а не слов как получалось у меня.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение

```
    $preg = '|^[A-Z\s]+\.+$|i';
    $check = preg_match($preg, $_POST['string']);
    if (($check == true)and (mb_substr_count($string, '.') == 1)) //не больше 1 точки
```

Отдельное спасибо Mike

> ну так добавьте эту самую точку перед концом строки т.е. перед $ не
>   забыв ее заэкранировать обратной косой – Mike

Comment: `(не больше 1)` не выполняется.

Comment: Можно использовать
(mb_substr_count($string, '.') == 1)
для проверки условия на одну точку в строке

Comment: Достаточно плюс убрать `'|^[A-Z\s]+\.$|i'`